# Gitlab Docker Registry fails with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab

I am trying to configure Gitlab Docker registry with an AWS S3 bucket for storage.

I just configure the Gitlab config file:

```
registry['storage'] = {
   's3' => {
     'accesskey' => 'ABCABCABC',
     'secretkey' => 'ABsndjsjdSJSJ',
     'bucket' => 'gitlab-registry',
     'region' => 'eu-west-1'
   }
 }
```

The problem is that when I try to login to the registry:

```
ikerlan@ikerlan:~$ sudo docker login https://gitlab.prueba.es:4567
Username: asier
Password:
```

I have the next error:

```
Error response from daemon: Login: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAVAILABLE","message":"service unavailable","detail":"health check failed: please see /debug/health"}]}
 (Code: 503; Headers: map[Server:[nginx] Date:[Fri, 24 Nov 2017 09:33:36 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=utf-8] Content-Length:[125]])
```

I read that some people disabled the registry health checks and it works, but how can I disable that registry health check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem adding a file to the S3 bucket.
The problem is that it was a Bug when the S3 bucket is empty, so adding any file to the bucket, the registry works. Then I remove the file and it works perfectly.